# Fitting jQuery mobile dialog to height and width of page, especially during orientation change

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, orientation

Is it possible to fit a jQuery mobile dialog to the height and width of a page, especially during orientation change on a tablet? I've tried wrapping a div inside the dialog and setting its height and width to percentages, but that has not worked for some reason.  Setting that div to a static width and height works fine, but then looks bad on orientation change.

Comment: could u show us what u tried?

Comment: I said that in the question.  I tried using percentages but for some reason CSS doesn't like percentages.